# How do I find the indices of a number along the length of vector C++?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

Suppose I have a vector A = {1,1,1,0,0};
Is there any inbuilt function in vector header to find all the indices of vector where A is repeated?
suppose for 1, returning, { 0,1,2 }
for 0, {3,4}

If not, is there any time efficient way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Essentially you are going to want to create a histogram but instead of counting the occurrence you want to register the index.  That can be done in `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

> If not, is there any time efficient way to do so?

Sort your vector and use `std::equal_range` to find iterators range, then convert them to indexes. If you cannot sort the vector, create vector of indexes, sort it and copy the range from it to result.

Comment: Thanks @Slava for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If the vector is or can be sorted, then you can use std::equal_range.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range

Comment: Thanks @Paul for answering